# Laravel Eloquent: route model binding not working with multi word table name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

i'm making a delete call with ajax to my destroy route for a model.
Everything works, except that the controller doesn't match the corresponding record in the database.

I call a `api/serviceoperations/17` ajax **delete** call, but if i place a `var_dump` in my controller in this way:

```
    public function destroy(ServiceOperation $serviceOperation) {
        var_dump($serviceOperation);die;
    }
```

i get an empty model that doesn't exists

```
 public 'exists' => boolean false
```

Of course I have a **model** called *ServiceOperation* that refers to the table *service_operations*, with the **primary key** `id`, and in my database there's a record with key `17`.

Why doesn't the controller resolves my id the route to the relative record in the db?

---

**update (solved):**

Model, Controller and Migration were created with the command

```
php artisan make:model -m -c -r App\Models\ServiceOperation
```

Anyway it seems that laravel doesn't hand very well table's name with more then one world:
While the command above works good with one word table name (ie App\Model\Service), it doesn't works with 2 or more, since it wouldn't bind by itself the model passed in the route.

The solution is to use the input variable name in controller with all lowercase character.
In my case, the **auto generated** destroy function in controller was

```
    public function destroy(ServiceOperation $serviceOperation) {
        //model bind not working
    }
```

But the model bind wasn't working.

Updating the parameter to a **lowercase** string, solve the issue, and model bind works:

```
    public function destroy(ServiceOperation $serviceoperation) {
        //model bind working
    }
```

Comment: How are you deleting the model object?

Comment: with `$serviceOperation->delete();`, but that's not the problem. the destroy function parameter is not resolved by eloquent as it should.

Comment: I've added a snippet, try that.

Comment: Just passing a model instance into the function and type hinting it, does not make your app magically know which row in the database you're referring to.

Comment: @Joe if you don't know what i'm talking about, read [something](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) before comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to use the input variable name in controller with all lowercase character.
In my case, the **auto generated** destroy function in controller was

```
    public function destroy(ServiceOperation $serviceOperation) {
        //model bind not working
    }
```

But the model bind wasn't working.

Updating the parameter to a **lowercase** string, solve the issue, and model bind works:

```
    public function destroy(ServiceOperation $serviceoperation) {
        //model bind working
    }
```

Comment: Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It was something wrong in the autogenerated code by Laravel.
I don't remember wich version of Laravel i was using, but if the bug is still there, which version are you using, so that i will update the description?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in the wild card provided in the route file
`Route::get('/serviceoperation/{wildcard}', 'PostsController@destroy');`
the `{wildcard}` has to match in your controller

```
public function destroy(ServiceOperation $wildcard) {
        //model bind working
    }
```

as long as this too names match, the model binding will work as long as the wildcard is the id

Comment: If you carefully read the question, teh method has been created with the command `php artisan make:model -m -c -r App\Models\ServiceOperation`, so the wildcard was autogenerated. The problem was that the parameter name has to be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with this thing -> [Laravel explicit bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#explicit-binding).
You can make explicit bindings in the RouteServiceProvider boot method like this:

```
/**
 * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('ServiceOperation', \App\ServiceOperation::class);
}
```

Comment: No, it already works with implicit binding. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#implicit-binding

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public function destroy(ServiceOperation $serviceOperation, $id) {
    $resource = $serviceOperation->find($id);

    return $resource->delete();
}
```

See, if that helps.

Comment: It should works, but that's not the point. It would works also `public function destroy($serviceOperation)`, but the "power" of eloquent is to resolve itself the id to the model

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you.